# Upgrading angular 4 admin panel to angular 7

Tags: webpack, angular7

I am upgrading my angular 4 admin panel to 7, the project makes use of webpack so does angular depends upon webpack version. The webpack version is 2.3.  I have followed the steps in angular update doc, but getting a series of errors related to webpack. My latest error is ngtools webpack" package installed not compatible version "ngc.Both ngTools and ngc-webpack are upto date.Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Angular version is 7

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.1",
"@ngtools/webpack": "^7.0.3",
"ngc-webpack": "^4.1.2"
}
```